# Corrupt JPEG data: extraneous bytes before marker, OpenCV C++, Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture, raspbian

I am trying to run OpenCV application on Raspberry PI. When video capture from an external camera starts (Logitech C270), the messages below are printed out:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extemporaneous bytes before marker 0x44
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extemporaneous bytes before marker 0x43
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extemporaneous bytes before marker 0x40
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extemporaneous bytes before marker 0x41
...
```

However, the application works all right on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine with same web camera.

It is because of `capture.read(frame)` part of the code

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Marged sorry for confusion. I would like to know why `read` function causes to those error messages and how can I solve this problem?